# How to track MSDTC error in NServicebus?

Tags: nservicebus

We got a weird error that we can't figure the cause of. It happened over 100 times in a matter of seconds and then it stopped.

**Stacktrace:**

```
System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionException: MSDTC was unable to read its configuration information. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D027) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: MSDTC was unable to read its configuration information. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D027)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Boolean& nodeNameMatches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle& whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException comException)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.get_ProxyShimFactory()
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.CreateTransaction(TransactionOptions properties)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromoted.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionTyp
```

Any ideas about how we can track the cause of this error?

Comment: Have you checked out the logs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: Do you use clustered DTC?